# How to solve $6^{x} + 8^{x} + 9^{x} = 12^{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-sum

I checked on WolframAlpha and it says the answer is approx. 2.56639, but I don't know how to go about solving this equation. What kind of approach should I use?

Comment: I think this was a numerical solution from wolfram alpha.

Comment: I dont know how to do that... maybe writing each exponential as a series or something like this. I dont know numerical methods.

Comment: @Masacroso: I'm sure you do, perhaps just not under that name. Have you heard about _bisection_? Or _Newton's method_? Those are numerical methods.

Comment: This is certainly more involved than I expected. I doubt the OP would have access to any useful numerical methods.

Comment: Yeah I don't know any numerical methods; my knowledge of math extends to combinatorics, linear algebra and multivariate calculus -- none of which are useful here haha. @HenningMakholm I got that far but there doesn't seem to be any way to use logarithms or something to simplify further because of the sum.

Comment: Newton's method is often taught in first-year calculus courses.

Comment: For example, see [these notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~keshet/M102/M102CourseNotes/M102chap5.pdf)

Comment: @HenningMakholm well, Im not mathematician and never get classes of mathematics at university level. I just read some topic that I like in my spare time... and calculus is not my preferred :p

Comment: Interesting! I wrote a Python script to do Newton's method and from an initial guess of 2.2 it converges really quickly (10 or so iterations) to 2.566.  With an initial guess of 2.1, however, it still doesn't converge after tens of thousands of iterations. Anyone know why this would be the case?

Comment: @Masacroso: Sorry, I confused you for the OP.

Comment: @dobse: See [this graph from Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5ex%2B8%5ex%2B9%5ex-12%5ex,+0%3Cx%3C3). If your starting guess is to the left of the hump, Newton-Raphson will keep moving out left, trying to find where the curve drops down to the x-axis. But it never does! So in this case (as in many others), it would be best to use bisection to aim coarsely at the root, and then perhaps switch to Newton-Raphson to pile on decimals if you want many of them.

Comment: (@dobse, my first comment was a response to a now deleted "hint" from YuriyS, which I found unhelpful ... my point was to show that this rewriting led nowhere.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm ahh I see! Interesting that I found the peak almost exactly by plugging in random numbers. Thanks for the help! Glad to see things I learned back in Calc 1 being put to use (:

Comment: You can convert this equation to : ab+a^3+b^2=a^2b with a,b>0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $$f(x)=6^{x} + 8^{x} + 9^{x} - 12^{x}$$ will not show any analytical solution and cannot be transformed in any polynomial. So, only numerical methods would give the result.

Plotting or using inspection, we know thet the solution is between $2$ and $3$ since $f(2)=37$ and $f(3)=-271$.

The simplest method is probably Newton which, starting from aguess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ So, let us apply the method starting using $x_0=3$. The iterates will then be $$x_1=2.78153052$$ $$x_2=2.63689146$$ $$x_3=2.57608481$$ $$x_4=2.56659523$$ $$x_5=2.56638730$$ $$x_6=2.56638720$$ which is the solution for nine significant figures.

As you see, the convergence has been rather slow (it would have been faster starting closer to the solution).

But instead of $f(x)$, consider the transform $$g(x)=\log(6^x+8^x+9^x)-\log(12^x)$$ If you plot the new function, it looks that it is almost a straight line and this is much much better. Let us repeat the same calculations starting from $x_0=3$ as before. The iterates are $$x_1=2.56168284$$ $$x_2=2.56638663$$ $$x_3=2.56638720$$ which is the solution for nine significant figures. Much faster, isn't it ?

Comment: Interesting, taking the log of the function and approximating using that! Thanks! Also, I'm curious: is there a specific reason why this equation can't be solved analytically? Or have I just been underexposed to the real world, having mostly only dealt with explicitly solvable equations?

Comment: @dobse. Glad to know that  you found the trick interesting. There is no analytical solution to transcendental equations. Be sure that there are, in real word, infinitely many equations which cannot be solved analytically ! Analytical solutions to equations are exceptions but very useful and important in studies. Let me give a simple case : what is the solution of $x=\cos(x)$ for $0<x<\frac \pi 2$ ? Cheers.